# Caching hundreds of routes in an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm migrating an ASP.NET webforms application to ASP.NET Core 5 MVC. The application has hundreds of routes. I need to add these routes to the `Configure` method in the `startup.cs`. I think the performance can be hit with hundreds of routes.

A few questions:

1. Is there any feature in ASP.NET Core 5 MVC that I can use to make the search in O(1) time?
2. I may stored these routes in a database, and need to be cached to make it faster. What is a native cache available in ASP.NET Core 5 MVC?
3. Is there a feature in the HTTP pipeline that helps the caching of the routes and selecting the view and controller

Comment: Is it feasible to migrate these routes into a pattern of say half a dozen templates? There's a lot you can do with areas, controllers actions and optional parameters before you need to think about custom resolvers or model conventions under the hood.

Comment: Could you please tell me what do you mean by templates? What I have is hundreds of routes and their corresponding webforms for them. One route has 2-4 forms and represents a full app. All these routes represent the same app backend (code behind) but with different front ends (webforms). The webforms differ in content but the form controls on the webforms are the same. All these routes are to do A/B testing. They keep growing when more tests are done. I'm trying to adopt the same from webform to MVC.